# Has a popular desktop application been developed in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I realize this may not be the best forum in which to ask this question (and I welcome suggestions for where to otherwise go), but I'm curious about the durability of distributing a wxPython application as an "enterprise" software product--it seems very doable considering pyinstaller accommodates packaging such a product very easily. Are there any examples of such projects/products?

Edit: looks like BitTorrent is built on wxPython

Comment: http://www.indicthreads.com/1063/wxpython-is-a-good-answer-for-almost-any-kind-of-desktop-application/

Comment: Define "popular".  How many people have to use it to pass the "popular" threshold?

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/users.htm

Comment: http://www.cambiumnetworks.com/products/software-tools/linkplanner/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list of wxPython applications is available here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonPit%20Apps

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know what your definition of popular is, but [Task Coach](http://taskcoach.org) is developed with Python and wxPython and has had 180K downloads this year so far.

Task Coach is available for Windows (using Inno Setup), all major Linux distributions (Debian packages and RPMs) and Mac OS X (as dmg).

Answer (score 1):

I think [Juice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_%28aggregator%29) uses wxWindows.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of [LINKPlanner](http://www.cambiumnetworks.com/products/software-tools/linkplanner/), This is scientific application written in wxPython. This is available for free, but you have to create an account to download and try it